# How to create and use a config file to choose a path of a decision tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, config

I have an application in Java that makes use of different mathematical models to classify and cluster some objects.

Currently, I am just hard coding which model I want to run and all its parameters.

I would like to set up a configuration file that allows for a certain sequence of steps to be taken. For example, here is a decision tree of a few possible paths.

```
model
    - model a
        - parameter a1
        - parameter a2
    - model b
        - object a
            - object_a_parameter1
            - object_a_paremeter2
        - parameter b

Apriori clusters:
    - set manually
    - automatic estimation
        - technique1
            - parameter 1
        - technique2
            - parameter 1
            - parameter 2
...
...
...
```

The difference between the above requirements and what I've found on google is that depending on which branch is taken, the number and types of inputs can vary. It's not just a [simple user name and password changes](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/), for example.

One thought I had was to have a top-level configuration file, and then a sub configuration for each step in the path taken. It seems too complicated though:

```
model : {
    type: "PAM"
    parameters_config : "some/other/file.json_or_whatever"
    }
    
apriori_k : {
    method : "spectral gap"
    parameters_config : "some/other/file.yaml_or_whatever"

}

similarity : {
    method : "Gaussian Kernel"
    parameter_config : "you/get/the idea"
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And even if this method is a good one, I have no idea how to get code to execute the defined steps based in the config file. Especially because some paths require extra objects and those objects have their own parameters too.

Is there an established best practice for this sort of thing? If not, what are some of my options?